# How to set up an untyped SOAP message + WSS in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, message, wss

soapUI creates a message to the service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.is.shit.com"> 
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">aIFkEUMZyhKuzGobh3CRpg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2011-09-20T09:33:11.545Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
      <body/>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

tell me how this can be created in the WCF?

As I understand it uses the class Message. But as with his help to get such a request - I do not understand. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: how to do the same in WCF? =)